# how to show image on click, and hide it again when clicking again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to when I click on a sentence or a button an image appears, and when I click it again it disappears. but my code doesn't seem to work using JS and HTML.

```js
let pic = document.getElementById("hiddenclickimg");
let word = document.getElementById("hiddenclick");

function showPic(){
  pic.hidden = 'false' ;
  word.style.color = 'red';
  word.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

word.onclick = showPic;
```

```html
<h3 id="Work">Work Experience</h3>
      <div class="work">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <img
              src="./Images/Alex Sydney.jpg"
              alt="alex sydney"
              id="hiddenclickimg"
              hidden="true"
            />
            <button id="hiddenclick">Alex Sydney Hospital</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

<script src="./main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding and removing a class is so much easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onclick of a button and [toggle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) a class that hides the image when it has that class.

HTML:

```
<button onclick="imageClick()">Toggle Image</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const image = document.getElementById('hiddenclickimg');

const imageClick = () => {
   image.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

There are different CSS properties you could use to hide the image, but opacity is a good basic one.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set 2 ids to do the trick using css property [display none](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp).

For example you want to hide that image:

```
<img id="dog_image" src="dog.png" alt="Rex the Labradoodle" >

function hideDog() {
  const dog = document.getElementById("dog_image");
  if (dog.style.display === "none") {
    dog.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    dog.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And then just set the button:

```
<button onclick="hideDog()">Hide/Show my dog</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use flag to change state of the image like following

```
let  imagehidden =false
let pic = document.getElementById('hiddenclickimg');
let word = document.getElementById('hiddenclick');

function showPic(){
if(imagehidden){
  pic.hidden = false ;
  word.style.color = 'red';
  word.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
  imagehidden=false
  }
  else{
   pic.hidden =true;
   imagehidden=true
  }
}
```